# Is there a way to enforce matching the virtual register in IR level to physical register?

Tags: assembly, llvm, inline-assembly, llvm-ir, riscv

I'm currently writing an inline assembly (a genuine '*bndr rd, rs1, rs2*' instruction) for LLVM IR. The destination register (rd) holds the pointer address for the following load/store instruction.
The instrumented IR code after pass looks like this:

```
call void asm sideeffect "bndr $0, $1, $2", "r, r, r"(%struct.SHA_INFO** %sha_info.addr, i8* %base, i8* %bound)
%2 = load %struct.SHA_INFO*, %struct.SHA_INFO** %sha_info.addr, align 8
```

and the assembly generated from from my backend looks like this:

```
        addi    a1, s0, -136
        addi    a2, a1, 8
        mv      a3, a1
        mv      a4, a2
        #APP
        bndr    a1, a3, a4
        #NO_APP
        ld      a3, -144(s0)
```

Although both inlined asm ***bndr*** and the ***load*** instruction in IR level are using the same virtual register "**%struct.SHA_INFO** **%sha_info.addr**". But in the assembly level, *bndr* use **a1** register for virtual register %sha_info.addr, while the *ld* use **-144(s0)** for the same virtual register.

My question is that is it possible to force the *bndr* or *ld* using same physical register for address?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know LLVM-IR well, but maybe try looking at the IR from clang compiling an `asm()` statement with asm-register local vars that force `"=r"` and `"r"` constraints to pick specific registers.  Like `register int foo asm("r0")`.

Comment: @PeterCordes the `"="` constraint means that this operand is write-only for this instruction: the previous value is discarded and replaced by output data. If I pick a specific register for my asm inline, the _load_ IR instruction can still pick up other physical registers than one that we assigned to _bndr_ .